# IOS CORS problems ionic 1 project and android work perfectly

Tags: http, ionic-framework, ionic2, cors

Hai friends I am ionic developer
My application work perfectly in android but it get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` I can not login to run another functionality

[image: Here is the server response header]

How can I call my api in ios application

I don't understand the error behind this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should provide more info on the request you`re trying to make and the headers you're using. CORS is an important subject on mobile developing. I`d try a bit of reading and playing around with your api on Postman for example.

Comment: Api work on postman as well as in chrome and android device problem only in ios mobile and safari